# Duplicate Completion Item Provider

Tags: monaco-editor

I have an instance of monaco editor running inside an iFrame inside of an angular 1.5 application. Whenever I load the editor, I use `registerCompletionItemProvider` to register a custom completion item.

However, when the editor is loaded for a second time, the completion item is registered again and I get duplicate completion items. This happens each successive time that I load the editor. I don't know when the user is going to navigate away from the editor, and my controller does not have access to the monaco editor's `dispose()` method. How can I ensure that I don't continue to re-register existing completions?

Thanks!

Comment: any solution for this ?

Comment: Not as I would like. I check to see if my completion provider `completionProvider = monacoScope.monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider` is defined. If it is, I do not define it again, eliminating duplicate completions.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of registerCompletionItemProvider provide dispose method. You can dispose it when the editor is unmount.

Comment: How do you determine when the editor is unmounted? I've successfully called the `dispose` method before and haven't seen any change in completion providers.

Comment: Can you share some examples?